# journalctl to delete log

Tags: journalctl

```
du -sh /var/log/journal/
201M    /var/log/journal/
journalctl --vacuum-size=10M
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/5fabef35e4144feb92a9d7177b21d4e4/system@5dc54ed9ad1e41a785428a8ae2e88877-000000000000255c-00056318d1d89bc3.journal (80.0M).
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/5fabef35e4144feb92a9d7177b21d4e4/system@5dc54ed9ad1e41a785428a8ae2e88877-0000000000018c73-0005657d4e6fa7a7.journal (48.0M).
Vacuuming done, freed 128.0M of archived journals on disk.
du -sh /var/log/journal/
73M /var/log/journal/
```

Why `journalctl --vacuum-size=10M` can't delete log until /var/log/journal is 10M?

Answer (score 3):

From [`man journalctl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/journalctl.1.html):

> Note that running `--vacuum-size=` has only an indirect effect on the
>   output shown by `--disk-usage`, as the latter includes active journal
>   files, while the vacuuming operation only operates on archived journal
>   files.

Looks like you have 73M's worth of active journal files.